# 'squadre' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I was writing some code for an IT-exercise, but I can't solve an error which is annoying me.
It occurs in this block of code:

```py
class squadre():
    def __init__(self, lista: list, nomeFile: str):
        
        self.nomeFile = nomeFile
        self.lista = lista

        print("Lettura file in corso... ")

        file = open(self.nomeFile, "r")

        righe = file.readlines()

        count = 0
        for i in range(len(righe)//9):
            dizionario = {}

            for riga in righe[count:count+9]:
                riga = riga.strip()

                elementi = riga.split(": ")

                try:
                    dizionario[elementi[0]] = int(elementi[1])
                except:
                    dizionario[elementi[0]] = elementi[1]

            count += 9

            self.lista.append(dizionario)

        file.close()

        self.lista.sort(key = lambda dizionario: dizionario["punti"], reverse = True)

        print("Lista caricata con successo!")

lista = squadre(lista, nomeFile)
```

The error occurs at "self.lista.append(dizionario)" and 'squadre' in the error stands for the name of the Class I made.

Now I'm going to explain my code:
This function **init** must initialize the class creating the object "lista" from reading a file that I created before.
It reads 9 lines for time to create a different dictionary every time to append to the list.

Someone can resolve this error for me? Thank you very much :3

Edit: I added the line where I create the class and the line when I create the object 'lista', but I remembered that I create the object twice with the same name in two different parts of the program ('lista = squadre(lista, nomeFile)' x2). Could be this the problem?

Comment: Can you show how you are creating your `squadre` objects? More generally, can you include enough code so that someone else can reproduce the error?

Comment: I edited the post. Is it more useful now? Sorry for all but this is my first question :/

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the problem... :/

`lista`, in the line `lista = squadre(lista, nomeFile)`, was: `<__main__.squadre object at 0x00...>`, so it couldn't be assigned to a new class object in that method (I think).

Sorry for the useless post, would I delete it? I don't know O.o

Comment: Typically you capitalize classes: `Squadre` and objects you create are often the lower case version, i.e. `squadre`, so `squadre = Squadre(lista, nomeFile)`